Paramiko how to check if current path is directory
I'm encountering an issue while working with the paramiko library, specifically regarding the SFTPClient module. I'm attempting to recursively download files from a directory, including all subdirectories and their contents. However, I'm facing difficulty determining whether a given path is a directory or not within the SFTPClient.
I'm using the latest version of paramiko (version 3.4.0). Below is the relevant portion of my Python code:
def download_files(self, local_dir):
    if self.sftp_instance:
        current_dir = self.sftp_instance.getcwd()
        local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, os.path.basename(current_dir))
        os.makedirs(local_path, exist_ok=True)

        files = self.get_list_of_files_in_current_dir()
        for item in files:
            remote_path = os.path.join(current_dir, item)
            item_local_path = os.path.join(local_path, item)
            print("Remote path:", remote_path)
            print("cwd", self.sftp_instance.getcwd())
            print("Is directory:", self.sftp_instance.stat(item).st_isdir())  # This line raises an AttributeError
            if self.sftp_instance.stat(remote_path).isdir():  # This is where I'm experiencing issues
                if not self.sftp_instance.listdir(remote_path):
                    print(f"Skipped empty directory: {item}")
                else:
                    self.sftp_instance.chdir(remote_path)
                    self.download_files(local_path)
                    self.sftp_instance.chdir("..")
            else:
                try:
                    self.sftp_instance.get(remote_path, item_local_path)
                    print(f"Downloaded file: {item}")
                except IOError as e:
                    print(f"Error downloading file: {item}")
                    print(f"Error message: {str(e)}")
                    print(f"Error details:")
                    print(f"  errno: {e.errno}")
                    print(f"  strerror: {e.strerror}")
                    print(f"  filename: {e.filename}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error downloading file: {item}. {str(e)}")
    else:
        print("SFTP connection not established. Please connect first.")

The specific line causing trouble is:
print("Is directory:", self.sftp_instance.stat(item).st_isdir())
This line raises the following error:
AttributeError: 'SFTPAttributes' object has no attribute 'st_isdir'

I've also attempted to use the isdir() method directly on the SFTPAttributes object returned by self.sftp_instance.stat(remote_path), but it appears that this method is not available.
Is there a different approach or method provided by the paramiko library that I should be using to determine whether a given path is a directory? Any insights or alternatives would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Great implementation of recursion!

Will definitely use it against my attempt

For the  stat() function call, return value is an object whose attributes correspond to the attributes of Python’s stat structure as returned by os.stat.
You can use the stat.S_ISDIR function to decide to whether the mode(st_mode) is a directory or not.
import stat
print("Is directory:", stat.S_ISDIR(self.sftp_instance.stat(item).st_mode))


While this is correct answer to the OP's literal question, it's wrong approach, as calling stat for each file individually is inefficient. For correct approach, see my answer to Recursive directory download with Paramiko?

@MartinPrikryl I don't have much experience with paramiko. The idea of my answer was to point out the stat.S_ISDIR. But yea, your solution seems to be more efficient. May be mark it as duplicate? I will delete this answer.

@Gabi can you unaccept my answer. I am unable to delete this

@Gobi, Please find the duplicated answer for a more efficient solution.
